# Сравнение кол-ва цифр до запятой и после

Tags: c++

Задача состоит в том что бы сравнить кол-во цифр в введённом числе до запятой и после. Второй день ломаю голову. Есть примерный алгоритм в голове, но на С++ не могу это написать, т.к. только начал изучать его.

Алгоритм(ИМХО):

1. Ввести число.
2. Задать 2 переменных sumA и sumB которые бы равнялись 0.
3. Делать итерацию через каждый элемент числа и увеличивать sumA на единицу.
4. Как только элемент будет равен точке либо запятой - пропустить его
5. Продолжить итерацию, но уже увеличивая sumB на единицу.
6. Сравнить sumA и (sumB - sumA)

Алгоритм может быть и скорее всего есть очень костыльный, т. к. я только начинающий программист, поэтому любая помощь приветствуется.

Comment: в каком формате вводятся данные?

Comment: @Saidolim cin >>

Comment: Делаешь машину состояний. Пока не встретилась точка, накапливается число цифр до запятой в каком-то регистре, после того, как точка встретилась, состояние меняется, и начинается вычитание из регистра. Если после работы алгоритма остался 0, то число цифр равно. Если отрицательное число, то после запятой больше цифр.

Comment: Получился какой-то такой плохо отлаживаемый и неоптимальный шлак, зато пришлось напрячься: https://ideone.com/Lol2pf

Comment: Нормальный алгоритм, всё правильно. Вот что делать _не_ нужно, так это вводить число типа `double` и пытаться считать цифры в _нём_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот код с использованием std::string. выводит на сколько различается количество позиций целого и дробного частей

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    string num;

    cout << "enter number: ";
    getline(cin, num);

    int num_left = num.find(","); // количество знаков до запятой
    int num_right = num.size() - num_left; // количество знаков после запятой

    cout << "---------result----------" << endl;

    if (num_left < num_right) // если в целой части числа меньше знаков чем в дробной части числа
        cout << "whole part number less fine part number on " << num_right - num_left << " positions" << endl;

    if (num_left > num_right) // если в целой части числа больше знаков чем в дробной части числа
        cout << "whole part number better fine part number on " << num_left - num_right << " positions" << endl;

    if (num_left == num_right) // если равны
        cout << "whole part number equal fine part number!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Основываясь на вашем алгоритме:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    printf("Enter number");
    int const arraySize = 20;
    int firstSequenceAmount = 0;
    int secondSequenceAmount = 0;
    char charArr[arraySize] = "\0";
    scanf("%s", charArr);
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
        if (charArr[i] == ',') {
            firstSequenceAmount = i;
            i++;
        }
        if (charArr[i] == '\0') {
            secondSequenceAmount = i - firstSequenceAmount - 1;
            break;
        }
     }
     printf("First piece: %d, second piece: %d", firstSequenceAmount, secondSequenceAmount);
     scanf(charArr);
     return 0;
 }
```